# wso2ei 6.4 - Return HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator

We are migrating services from WSO2 ESB  4.7 to WSO2 EI 6.4.

The problem is that when we call a ESB soap 1.1 service this is executed correctly but the client (SoapUI in this case) receives a response code 202 with       content-lenght 0 (status: HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted).

In carbon log we find this record: [SynapseWorker-2]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} -  Trying to submit a response to an already closed connection : http-incoming-1
The problem is not a timeout and if we change in SoapUI the content-type from request header we have a response with content-lenght > 0
Axis2 is configurated with text/xml enable both in Message Formatters and in Message Builders.

Any idea in order to address/solve the problem?

Comment: Any intermediate reverse proxy in between? Header keep alive have to be turned off)

Answer (score 0):

The message you're seeing: "Trying to submit a response to an already closed connection", could mean that the connection was closed by either the client or some operation inside your proxy/sequence. Are you handling the errors within the fault sequence?

I usually get unexpected 202 when there's something wrong with my service. It can be unhandled errors, not having <respond/> on the right place (like when using clone/iterate mediators without minding the threading behind these)...

My suggestion is to use logs and also [debugging](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Debugging+Mediation) to see what happens before you get the 202 or the "Trying to submit a response to an already closed connection" message.